# How can I transform a div to a tilted perspective?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm trying to transform my div like the green box.

[image]

I want to get 3D transform, not mask :

[image]

I find a way with [this generator](http://westciv.com/tools/3Dtransforms/index.html) but the css code doesn't work on my fiddle:

```
/*transform css3*/ 
#screen { 
    transform: scale(1.0) scaleZ(1.0) rotateX(-16deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    perspective: 450;
    perspective-origin: 100% 50%;
}
```

[image]

```css
body {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#mask {
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBK0O.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:350px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
}

#screen:hover {
    background:url(https://www.actugaming.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Assassins-Creed-Odyssey_Leak_06-10-18_015-1.jpg);
    background-size:100%;
}

#screen {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:38px;
    background:red;
    opacity:0.6;
}
   
#screen { 
    left:70px;
    width:240px;
    height:calc(240px * 9 / 16); /*keep 16/9 !*/
}

/*transform css3*/ 
#screen { 
    transform: scale(1.0) scaleZ(1.0) rotateX(-16deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    perspective: 450;
    perspective-origin: 100% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="mask">
<div id="screen"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: works in firefox, if what you want is exactly what you show above. if you want it on the other div, you'd have to put the style there..

Comment: I want to get my picture like the green div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need rotation and also a perspective to have the bottom right as origin. Note that perspective need to be applied to a parent element:

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  perspective-origin:bottom right;
  perspective:100px;
}

img {
  margin:30px 50px;
  transform:rotateX(-8deg);
  width:250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<img src="https://www.actugaming.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Assassins-Creed-Odyssey_Leak_06-10-18_015-1.jpg" >
</div>
```

Or use perspective inside the transform and adjust the origin of transform not origin of perspective:

```css
img {
  margin: 30px 50px;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-8deg);
  width: 250px;
  transform-origin: bottom right
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://www.actugaming.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Assassins-Creed-Odyssey_Leak_06-10-18_015-1.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: OH! perspective properties need to be in the parent rules !

Answer (score 5):

<strike>If you want that shape, you could use `clip-path` instead of using `transform`. This gives you a great amount of control over the shape you get. Here's a good tool to help you out: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/</strike>

Using `transform`, you can skew the image to achieve a 3d effect on the background/div content.

```css
#screen:hover {
  background: url(https://www.actugaming.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Assassins-Creed-Odyssey_Leak_06-10-18_015-1.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
}

#screen {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.6;
  left: 70px;
  width: 240px;
  height: calc(240px * 9 / 16);
  /*keep 16/9 !*/
  
  transform-origin: bottom right;
    -ms-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
    transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="screen"></div>
```

Comment: That good, i can also use `mask` property to do that but i need 3d transform to get 3d effect on my background/div content.

Comment: @A-312 I see what you mean now, I have updated my answer for you :-) Hope this helps.

Comment: But the left top corner and the right top corner move together. :/

Comment: On http://westciv.com/tools/3Dtransforms/index.html i find something but i can't get the same thing on my code. :/

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `transform: skew`, this is a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) for W3Schools explaining the `skew` transform, for your div you can add this line

```
#screen {
    transform: scale(1) skew(23deg);
}
```

Comment: I can't deform my div with that. :/

Answer (score 0):

Like I said [in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54828843/how-can-i-transform-a-div-to-a-tilted-perspective/54830209#comment96436113_54830209). I don't set perspective property in the good direction ! With some change I got the good render :

[image: final render]

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#mask {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBK0O.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 16px;
  /*perspective-origin:45% 1%;*/
  perspective-origin: 355px 2px;
}

#perpectiveorigin {
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  left:352px;
  top:-1px;
}

#screen:hover {
  background: url(https://www.actugaming.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Assassins-Creed-Odyssey_Leak_06-10-18_015-1.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
}

#screen {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 26px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#screen {
  left: 47px;
  width: 252px;
  height: calc(252px * 9 / 16);
  /*keep 16/9 !*/
}


/*transform css3*/

#screen {
  transform: rotateX(-1.05deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="mask">
  <div id="screen"></div>
</div>
<div id="perpectiveorigin"></div>
```